# Implement logout in Spring for Single Page Application

Tags: java, spring

I'm using **Java Web Token (JWT)** for authentication in my web app. I want to create a `/logout` Rest endpoint that deletes the JSession cookie on the client side, invalidates the session AND does whatever else is necessary.

The front end is a SPA written in React.

I have the following `configure` method in the `WebSecurityConfig` class that extends `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter`:

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
        .csrf().disable()
        .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/login").permitAll()
        .and()
        .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/signup").permitAll()
        .and()
        .authorizeRequests()
            .anyRequest().authenticated()
        .and()
        .addFilterBefore(
            new JWTAuthenticationFilter(userDetailsServiceBean()),
            UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);
}
```

I had the following code, but it returns `404 Not found` error with the path set to `/login`. I want to get a `HTTP response` of `200` and some cleanups instead. what should I do ?

```
.logout().logoutUrl("/logout").logoutSuccessHandler(logoutHandler).logoutSuccessUrl("/login").invalidateHttpSession(true)
```

Answer (score 1):

After some research I found out that if I want to use stateless Rest API design, I shouldn't use any cookie, including JSESSIONID.

Therefore I changed my code to:

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
        .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
        .and()
        .csrf().disable()
        .authorizeRequests()
            .anyRequest().authenticated()
        .and()
        .addFilterBefore(
            new JWTAuthenticationFilter(userDetailsServiceBean()),
            UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Could you first try for login request like this. First add **JWTLoginFilter** in your **WebSecurityConfig**.

Pasting code from my sample project:

```
http.csrf().disable() // disable csrf for our requests.
    .authorizeRequests()
    .antMatchers("/").permitAll()
    .antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST,"/login").permitAll()
    .anyRequest().authenticated()
    .and()
    // We filter the api/login requests
    .addFilterBefore(new JWTLoginFilter("/login", authenticationManager()), UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class)
    // And filter other requests to check the presence of JWT in header
    .addFilterBefore(new JWTAuthenticationFilter(), UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class)
    .addFilterBefore(new CORSFilter(), ChannelProcessingFilter.class);
```

You wouldn't require CORSFilter if your front end and back end are on same server.

Also find below JWTLoginFilter class

```
   public class JWTLoginFilter extends AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter 
    {
    private TokenAuthenticationService tokenAuthenticationService;
    public JWTLoginFilter(String url, AuthenticationManager authenticationManager) {
     super(new AntPathRequestMatcher(url));
     setAuthenticationManager(authenticationManager);
     tokenAuthenticationService = new TokenAuthenticationService();
}

@Override
public Authentication attemptAuthentication(HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest, HttpServletResponse httpServletResponse)
throws AuthenticationException, IOException, ServletException {
    AccountCredentials credentials = new ObjectMapper().readValue(httpServletRequest.getInputStream(), AccountCredentials.class);
    UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken token = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(credentials.getUsername(), credentials.getPassword());
    return getAuthenticationManager().authenticate(token);
}

@Override
protected void successfulAuthentication(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain chain, Authentication authentication)
throws IOException, ServletException {
    String name = authentication.getName();
    tokenAuthenticationService.addAuthentication(response, name);
  }
}
```

AccountCredential class is simple POJO class containing two fields username and password, which I was using to receive the request.

Also please note that **UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter** that we are using require two fields in login request 'username' and 'password'. Like `{"username":"user1","password":"secret1"}`